# PHP GET String with explode and if statements

Tags: php, redirect, if-statement, get, explode

I am writing what I thought would be a simple script but I am stuck.

The scenario is that I want to create 2 strings from the GET request.

eg:  domain.com/script.php?Client=A12345

In script.php it needs to grab the "Client" and create 2 variables.  One is $brand and needs to grab the A or B from the URL.  The Other is $id which needs to grab the 12345 from the URL.

Now, after it has these 2 variables $brand and $id it needs to have an if statement to redirect based on the brand like below

```
if ($brand=="A") {
header('Location: http://a.com');
}
if ($brand=="B") {
header('Location: http://b.com');
```

At the end of each URL I want to apend the $id though and I am unsure on how to do this.

So for example I would access the script at domain.com/script?Client=A1234 and it needs to redirect me to a.com/12345

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do a simple string concatenation? `'Location: http://a.com/'.$id`

Comment: Where did you buy these domain names: `a.com` and `b.com`?

Comment: @bsdnoobz  They are fictional and only for example :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$fullCode = $_REQUEST['Client'];
if(strpos($fullCode, 'A') !== false) {
   $exp = explode('A',$fullcode);
   header('Location: http://a.com/' . $exp[1]);
}
else if(strpos($fullCode, 'B') !== false) {
   $exp = explode('B',$fullcode);
   header('Location: http://b.com/' . $exp[1]);
}
else {
   die('No letter occurence');
}
```

Comment: This is similar to what I had but the same issue it is not appending the ID to the end of the URL

Comment: Ahhh, seems we both had the same issue, fullcode should be fullCode in $exp = explode('A',$fullcode);

Comment: You define $fullCode and then use $fullcode in both explode's. PHP is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do,

```
$value = $_GET['Client'];

$brand = substr($value, 0, 1);

$rest  = substr($value, 1, strlen($brand)-1);
```

now you have the first character in $brand string and you can do the if statement and redirect the way you want...

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?
**Notice:** 
this will only work if brand is just 1 character long. If that's not the case, please give better examples.

```
<?php

$client = $_GET['Client'];
$brand = strtolower(substr($client, 0, 1));
$id = substr($client, 1);

if ($brand == 'a')
{
    header("Location: http://a.com/$id");
}
elseif ($brand == 'b')
{
    header("Location: http://b.com/$id");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
preg_match("/([A-Z])(\d*)/",$_GET['Client'],$matches);
```

`$matches[1]` will contain the letter and `$matches[2]` will contain your id.

Then you can use:

```
if ($matches[1]=="A")
{
    header('Location: http://a.com/{$matches[2]}');
}
if ($matches[1]=="B")
{
    header('Location: http://b.com/{$matches[2]}');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

suggest you could also try

```
$requested = $_GET["Client"];
$domain = trim(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/',' ', $requested)); // replace non-alphabets with space
$brand = trim(preg_replace('/[a-zA-Z]/',' ', $requested)); // replace non-numerics with space
$redirect_url = 'http://' . $domain . '/' . $brand;
header('Location:' . $redirect_url);
```

but it'd be better if you could get the domain name and brand as two individual parameters and sanitize them individually before redirecting them to prevent the overhead of extracting them from a single parameter.

Note: this expression might be useless when the domain name itself has numerics and because the Client is obtained through get a good deal of validation and sanitation would be required in reality.

Answer (score 0):

```
$brand = strtolower($_GET['Client'][0]);
$id    = substr($_GET['Client'], 1);

header("Location: http://{$brand}.com/{$id}");
```

Answer (score 0):

If for some purpose you want to use explode, then you need to have a separator.
Let's take '_' as the separator, so your example would be something like this: domain.com/script.php?Client=A_12345

```
$yourstring = explode("_",$_GET["Client"]);

echo $yourstring[0];
//will output A 
echo $yourstring[1];
//will output 12345

//your simple controller could be something like this
switch($yourstring[0]){
case: 'A':
    header('Location: http://a.com?id='.$yourstring[1]);
    exit();
    break;

case: 'B':
    header('Location: http://b.com?id='.$yourstring[1]);
    exit();
    break;

default:
//etc
}
```